# First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty rails 4 Associated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a provider model which has many comments. I have a current setup working with the form being:

views/comments/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for([@provider, Comment.new] ) do |f| %>

<%= f.text_area :body, cols: 30, rows: 4, class: 'form-control' %>
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id, class: "form-control" %>
<div>
</br>
<%= f.submit :post, class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg' %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

But I dont think its right from what iv seen around it should be

```
<%= form_for([@provider, @comment[) do |f| %>
```

but this method I get the following error

```
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
```

I access my comments form from within my provider show.html.erb like this

```
<%= render 'comments/form', provider: @provider %>
```

My comments views are just _form.html.erb and _comments.html.erb which lists all the comments for a given provider.

My comments_controller.rb is as follows

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

before_action :set_provider

def new
 @comment = Comment.new
end

def create
 @provider = set_provider
 @comment = @provider.comments.create!(comment_params)
 redirect_to @provider
end

def destroy
 @provider = set_provider
 @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
 @comment.destroy
 redirect_to @provider
end

private

def set_provider
 @provider = Provider.find(params[:provider_id])
end

def comment_params
 params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :user_id)
end
end
```

If anyone point me in the right direction that would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.

Because I was showing the Comments in the show action of my provider model I needed this in the Provider

```
def show
 @comment = Comment.new
 @provider = find_provider
end
```

Works perfectly now.